# Selecting a row for every date during a particular period

Tags: sql

If I have records in a table that are timestamped how do I query so that I get the results for each day for each user as a row in the resultset along with additional info from another table?

Example:

batch_log

```
id  |  userid | batchid | start_time         | end_time            |time_elapsed
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  bob    | 123sgd  |2011-06-23 18:00:00 | 2011-06-23 18:12:00 | 00:12:00
2   |  jim    | 234sgd  |2011-06-22 12:00:00 | 2011-06-22 12:12:00 | 00:12:00
3   |  bob    | 1234gd  |2011-06-23 19:00:00 | 2011-06-23 19:08:00 | 00:08:00
4   |  bob    | 1Abeds  |2011-06-22 19:00:00 | 2011-06-23 20:24:00 | 00:24:00
```

screwups

```
id  |  userid | time_of_screwup
---------------------------------------------
1   |  bob    |2011-06-23 19:29:16 
2   |  jim    |2011-06-23 16:29:24
3   |  bob    |2011-06-22 12:29:16 
4   |  bob    |2011-06-23 13:29:16
```

How do I select so that I can get both the time elapsed and the number of screwups daily for each person so that I can feed this into excel.

Example output:

```
  userid | date       |COUNT(time_elapsed)| COUNT(screwups)|
------------------------------------------------------------
  bob    | 2011-06-23 | 00:20:00          |   2
  jim    | 2011-06-22 | 00:12:00          |   1
  bob    | 2011-06-22 | 00:24:00          |   1
```

EDIT: Data that makes more sense

Comment: A join plus a GROUP BY DATE('time_of_screwup') could be useful in your case. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an `id` field on your results doesn't really make sense, so I'll just ignore that that field exists.  Similarly, I doubt that `time_elapsed` will be the same for different job runs on the same day, so we'll knock that out.

Getting rid of those two fields leaves us with a fairly straightforward `GROUP BY` query.  I don't know the specifics of your database so, for the purposes of this problem, I'll assume that your DB has a `DATE()` function that returns the date part of a timestamp.  Unless you left out important details in your question , the existence of the `batch_log` table is a red herring.  You really just want to `SELECT userid, DATE(time_of_screwup), count(*) FROM screwups GROUP BY userid, DATE(time_of_screwup)`.

Comment: Yeah, copy paste errors, its not accurate data its a quick hackup.

Comment: I need the batch_log for the time_elapsed.

Comment: If a user runs two jobs on the same day, it's almost certain that `time_elapsed` will be different.  If there's screwups in both jobs, unless you explain your question much better, there's no sensible way to return this value.  If you want a proper answer, you'll have to reformulate your question to more clearly express what you're trying to get.Either way, storing `time_elapsed` in your database is highly redundant, since you have a start and end time on the record anyways.

Comment: I'm not the one who stores it. What I want on the time_elapsed a sum of it. I'll rephrase my question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do the trick. To handle the case where a batch run spans days (e.g., it starts at 11:50pm on June 30 and completes on 12:10am on July 1), we arbitrarily assign the event to a single day, based on its start time.

Since you haven't specified a RDBMS, this code is for SQL Server. It makes the assumption that the date/time values are a SQL Server DATETIME and that the elapsed time is represented as a datatype that SUM() can work with — a numeric value, perhaps.

```
select userid             = t.userid ,
       report_date        = t.dtEvent ,
       total_batch_runs   = sum( case is_batch when 1 then 1 else 0 end ) ,
       total_screwups     = sum( case is_batch when 1 then 0 else 1 end ) ,
       total_elapsed_time = sum( t.elapsed_time ) ,
from ( select userid       = userid             ,
              is_batch     = 1 ,
              dtEvent      = date( start_time ) , -- date() only appropriate for SQL Server 2008
              elapsed_time = time_elapsed ,
       from dbo.batch_log
       UNION ALL
       select userid       = userid ,
              is_batch     = 0 ,
              dtEvent      = date( time_of_screwup ) , -- date() only appropriate for SQL Server 2008
              elapsed_time = null 
       from dbo.screwups
     ) t
group by t.userid , t.dtEvent
```

Comment: It's MYSQL. I didn't know you could do this sort of stuff in SQL.